# Android Retrofit Get child object of child object

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to get the child object `Data` which is a child object of `Children` which if a child object of `Data`.

I know it sound really confusing, but here is the full JSON object:
[Full JSON](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/hot.json?limit=1)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Path;

public class GitHubClient {
    private static final String API_URL = "http://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/";

    static class Data {
        String kind;
        List<Children> children;
    }

    static class Children {
        Data data;
    }

    interface Reddit {
        @GET("/hot.json?limit=1")
        List<Data> data();
    }

    public static void main() {
        // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API endpoint.
        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(API_URL)
                .build();

        // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
        Reddit reddit = restAdapter.create(Reddit.class);

        // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to this library.
        List<Data> data = reddit.data();
        for (Data child : data) {
            System.out.println(child.kind);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two errors with your design in itself.

1. the JSON returned is not an Array but an object so trying to store in list is incorrect.
2. the array called children is an array of Data objects not an array of Children.Data

you can handle this with one class Data only no point of having Children class.

```
static class Data {
    String kind;
    String modhash;
    Data data;
    List<Data> children;
}
```

Next up is accessing these values in main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitHub API endpoint.
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_URL)
            .build();

    // Create an instance of our GitHub API interface.
    Reddit reddit = restAdapter.create(Reddit.class);

    // Fetch and print a list of the contributors to this library.
    Data data = reddit.data();
    for (Data child : data.data.children) {
        System.out.println(child.kind);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that is easier! 

But, I can't figure out how to get the `title` element from the `children` > `data` object

Comment: use `System.out.println(child.data.kind)` in the loop